# ASP.NET Caching suggestion

Tags: asp.net, caching, sqlcachedependency

I have an ASP.NET website for which I want to implement ASP.NET caching. There is a master list of items that only master users can see when they login. All other users only see a subset of the master list.

I want to cache the master list using SqlCacheDependency but I don't think I can because SqlCacheDependency works with queries that involve tables from single database only.
Unfortunately, my master list is stored in several databases and it does get updated now and then.

What is the best way in my situation to cache the master list but still keep it up to date?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not you use Cache object ?

Comment: I can but I will have to invalidate the cache object as soon as the query result changes i.e the master list is modified. I looked at query notification but it doesn't work with sub-queries,joins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the .net cache to store your objects?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx